# Word read the same from backword or forward

Tags: python, string, class, slice

Can anybody help me and tells me what is the thing that is missing

```
class Palindrome:

  @staticmethod
  def is_palindrome(word):
    copy_ = word[-1:]
    if word == copy_:
       return True
     else:
       return False


  print(Palindrome.is_palindrome("deleveled"))
```

Comment: just change word[-1:] to word[::-1]

Comment: replace word[-1:] by word[::-1]

Comment: guys it also gives me an error saying the word is not defined why? @lupanoide and thank you

Comment: @Skiller Dz  thanks bro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
copy_ = word[-1:]
```

To:

```
copy_ = word[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`word[-1:]` just **returns** the last character of the `word`.

Replace

```
copy_ = word[-1:]
```

with

```
copy_ = word[::-1]
```

The `[::-1]` slice inverting the string

Another method is to use `reverse` function.

```
copy_ = ''.join(reversed(word))
```

**Note:**  `word[::-1]` is faster.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut reason for `word[::-1]` being faster?

Comment: @JeruLuke Timings (and the reasons for them) for various ways to implement reversing a string are given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python.